# Формат даты в скриншоте Node.js

Tags: node.js, datetime, screenshots

Есть работающий код по созданию Full скрина на Node.js:

```
   var nodejsScreenCapture = require("nodejs-screen-capture")
   var date_time = Date.now();

   let  width = 512;
   let  height = 384;
   let format = 'png';
   let file = 'screen'+date_time+'.png';

   nodejsScreenCapture.captureAndSave(width, height, format, file);
   console.log('image succesfully');
```

В результате выполнения получаем картинку в файлике типа такого: screen1600717421592.png.
Хочется видеть дату и время в названии файла, а не миллисекунды.
В Node.js новичок, уровня ниже юниорского. Поэтому прошу варианты у более опытных людей.

Comment: P.S. Прошу прощения за описку в заголовке: Node.js - правильное написание.

Comment: У вас разве нет кнопки "править"? [Вот тут](https://i.imgur.com/srHyuRo.png)

Comment: Ein - когда вопрос создал не было - у меня ноут, видимо, багануло))
А сейчас нашел.

Answer (score 3):

Документация: [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
let n = new Date();


let date = `${n.getFullYear()}_${n.getMonth()+1}_${n.getDate()}`;
let time = `${n.getHours()}_${n.getMinutes()}_${n.getSeconds()}`;

let name = `screen${date}-${time}.jpg`;

console.log(name)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!